# How do I properly link the Google Protocol Buffers library with my application at compilation?

Tags: gcc, protocol-buffers, ld, linker-flags, abseil

I am following the tutorial listed [here](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/cpptutorial/) on Protobuf's website. I copied the sample `addressbook.proto` and compiled it using the line

```
protoc --cpp_out=. addressbook.proto
```

Which produced `addressbook.pb.cc` and `addressbook.pb.h`. Here is my program, which doesn't do anything right now (I am just trying to get it to compile).

```
#include "addressbook.pb.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

My problem arises at compilation. I thought this would suffice:

```
g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp addressbook.pb.cc -o main -L/usr/local/lib64 -lprotobuf -lprotoc -lprotobuf-lite -lpthread
```

However, I get enough linker errors to fill my terminal's history, pretty much all of them start with

```
undefined reference to `absl::lts_20230125:: ...
```

I tried manually installing Abseil from source by following the [directions here](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/quickstart-cmake), which put the `*.a` files in `/usr/local/lib64`.

I tried using `-L` to specify the original build directory to the linker (before installation).

I found a list of 60-70 Abseil-related linker flags which I tried to incorporate into my [compilation command](https://pastebin.com/UuLpLE56).

I tried various assortments of compiler/linker flags, enivronment variables, and recompiling Protobuf and Abseil, all resulting in the same thing.

For the record, I installed Protocol Buffers from source by following the CMake directions [specified here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/cmake/README.md). My GCC version is 8.3.1 (via devtoolset-8 on CentOS 7.9). I made sure to include the `-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14` flag when building. For me, it is installed at `/usr/local/lib64`.

I imagine I'm making a simple mistake somewhere or I'm missing something basic since protobuf is a well-known library, but I'm really stumped here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To anyone curious, I just uninstalled all the Protobuf and Abseil libraries and installed Protobuf 3.20.1, which doesn't depend on Abseil. This gave me no issues.